# Getting the source for something that doesn't seem to have an associated package?

Tags: apt, source

I recently just wanted to look at the source code for `sha1sum`.

```
alec@ROOROO:~/tmp-source-study$ apt-get source sha1sum
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for sha1sum
```

The next thing I did was to read the manual. The manual mentioned coreutils. But I don't see anything like `sha1sum.c`, and there's no associated Debian package for sha1sum, as far as I can tell.

What should I be doing to get the source code for this small, basic program without having to use a search engine, from the convenience of my shell?

Comment: There is not necessarily a file named `sha1sum.c`. It can be basically any file  or multiple files providing the functionality. If you grep for `sha1` in the `src` folder you will notice that `src/md5sum.c` is the file used to compile sha1sum. Oh and jftr `coretuils` is the  right package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find which package the file is from:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/bin/sha1sum
coreutils: /usr/bin/sha1sum
```

And then install the source:

```
% apt-get source coreutils
```

Comment: ok. i did do that originally, (except i didn't know `dpkg -S`: that's handy) but i guess i have to look harder for the source next time.